# Warning Db.prototype.authenticate method even after version 4.11.1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, protractor

Getting warning "Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the
admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials."

I saw it should be resolved after mongoose 4.11.1.But still I'm getting this warning.

I have "mongoose": "^4.13.9"and
node: "8.9.3"

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let client = null;

module.exports = {
connect: function () {
    var dbConnection = mongoose.connect("xxx", {}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error occurred' + err);
        }
    });       
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing `{ useMongoClient: true }` as one of the options to mongoose.connect() should remove the warning.